# phpmyadmin update m to n relationship table to remove duplicates from separate table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE designs
    ( game_id       INT     NOT NULL,
      des_id        INT     NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(game_id, des_id),
      FOREIGN KEY(game_id) REFERENCES Game(id),
      ON UPDATE CASCADE)

CREATE TABLE designer
    ( name      VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
      id        INT             NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(id),
      FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES designs(des_id),
      ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Lets say I have data:

designs:

0---0

0---1

1---2

2---3

2---4

.............................

designer:

Bob---0

Jill---1

Bob---2

Rob---3

Jill---4

After the update, I would like the "designs" table to look like:

0---0

0---1

1---0

2---3

2---1

What update query would I need to accomplish this?

Some queries I tried are:

```
UPDATE designs
SET des_id = (
SELECT a.id
FROM designer as a
JOIN designer as b
ON a.name=b.name AND a.id < b.id
WHERE des_id = b.id);
```

...

```
UPDATE `designs` as a
JOIN designer as b
ON a.des_id=b.id
SET a.des_id = b.id
WHERE b.id = (
SELECT c.id
FROM designer as c
LEFT JOIN designer as d
ON c.name=d.name
WHERE c.id<d.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea. Note that it uses an documented hack in the form of a 'group by/order by' trick:

```
UPDATE designs d 
 JOIN 
    ( select d1.id matcher_id 
           , d2.id select_id 
        from `designer` d1  
        JOIN designer d2 
          ON d1.name = d2.name 
       group 
          by d1.id 
       Order 
          by d2.id
    ) x  
   ON x.matcher_id = d.des_id 
  SET d.des_id = select_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your LEFT JOIN idea is almost right, but here's another idea which is faster...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS designs;

 CREATE TABLE designs
     ( game_id INT NOT NULL 
     , designer_id INT NOT NULL
     , PRIMARY KEY(game_id, designer_id)
     );

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS designers;

 CREATE TABLE designers
     ( name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
     , designer_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
     );

 INSERT INTO designs VALUES 
 (1,1),
 (1,2),
 (2,3),
 (3,4),
 (3,5);

 INSERT INTO designers VALUES 
 ('Bob',1),
 ('Jill',2),
 ('Bob',3),
 ('Rob',4),
 ('Jill',5);

 SELECT * FROM designs;
 +---------+-------------+
 | game_id | designer_id |
 +---------+-------------+
 |       1 |           1 |
 |       1 |           2 |
 |       2 |           3 |
 |       3 |           4 |
 |       3 |           5 |
 +---------+-------------+

 SELECT * FROM designers;
 +------+-------------+
 | name | designer_id |
 +------+-------------+
 | Bob  |           1 |
 | Jill |           2 |
 | Bob  |           3 |
 | Rob  |           4 |
 | Jill |           5 |
 +------+-------------+

 UPDATE designs g
   JOIN designers d
     ON d.designer_id = g.designer_id
   JOIN designers x ON x.name = d.name
   JOIN
      ( SELECT name
             , MIN(designer_id) min_designer_id
          FROM designers
         GROUP
            BY name
      ) y
     ON y.name = x.name
    AND y.min_designer_id = x.designer_id
    SET g.designer_id = x.designer_id;

 SELECT * FROM designs;
 +---------+-------------+
 | game_id | designer_id |
 +---------+-------------+
 |       1 |           1 |
 |       1 |           2 |
 |       2 |           1 |
 |       3 |           2 |
 |       3 |           4 |
 +---------+-------------+
```

Actually, in the special case of an UPDATE, I think this will work just as well, and I'm not really sure that it's any less performative...

```
UPDATE designs g
  JOIN designers x
    ON x.designer_id = g.designer_id
  JOIN designers y
    ON y.name = x.name
   AND y.designer_id < x.designer_id
   SET g.designer_id = y.designer_id;
```

Comment: This worked. But first I had to **remove the foreign key** in my designer table because of a foreign key constraint. Secondly, I had to remove both **ON UPDATE CASCADE** because updating the designs table would cause a primary key constraint error in the designer table.